# Trouble getting started with gradle springboot and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Java project in eclipse where i have used mysql earlier i implemented spring and i am now about to switch database to postgresql and i also want to implement springboot with gradle and switch my xml based config to java based config. in xml i have the following dataconfig.xml and when i swapped the earlier jdbc for mysql to jdbc for postgresql i got the app running on server.

```
<!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface, configuring 
        the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/up2u_user" />
        <property name="username" value="up2u_user2" />
        <property name="password" value="e2f2c2ac87" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory; rather than 
        application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="se.up2u.flowkeeper.*" />

        <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager. Exposes 
            Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

now to my problem i have the following files in my new springboot gradle project...

This is my application.properties file.

```
# General JPA properties
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/up2u_user
spring.datasource.username=up2u_user2
spring.datasource.password=password

# Hibernate Specific properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

This is my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java:2.0.0'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

This is my application file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@EntityScan("se.up2u.flowkeeper.model.entity")
public class FlowKeeperCoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlowKeeperCoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration file that's quite empty atm...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FlowKeeperConfig {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and when i try to run "gradle bootRun" i get the following stack-trace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: class demo.fabric.Employee not found while looking for property: id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2                                                        .RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at se.up2u.flowkeeper.FlowKeeperCoreApplication.main(FlowKeeperCoreApplication.java:16) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class demo.fabric.Employee not found while looking for property: id
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindSimpleEntityIdentifier(ModelBinder.java:712) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindEntityIdentifier(ModelBinder.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindRootEntity(ModelBinder.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindEntityHierarchy(ModelBinder.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.ja                  r:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common fmittedo
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [demo.fabric.Employee]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : demo.fabric.Employee
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I have understood that much that i should define beans to replace the default once but i don't really know how to do it? i have searched but haven't really understod what beans to create, what properties to change or what dependencies that is missing or unnecessary.

UPPDATE:
The class and package that is mentioned in the stack trace is not in my project. i use package structure se.up2u.flowkeeper
I just realised that the jdbc i use is what postgresql is referingto as jdbc41 that is intended for java 1.7 there is no jdbc42 that is for 1.8. also i get another error about unsatisfied dependency if i remove the postgresql dependency.

Comment: Error says your Entity class `demo.fabric.Employee` doesn't have a field that has been annotated as `@Id`. `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class demo.fabric.Employee not found while looking for property: id`

Comment: Yes but that is no class that i have in my project. i use packages named se.up2u.flowkeeper. and so on. when i add @Bean with entetymanagerFactory i get another error about TransactionManager but i cent get it all figured out it feels like i have missed something obvious.

Comment: Are running `gradle` from `Eclipse`? Check your classpath, it looks like you added another project as a dependency. BTW: https://github.com/asanciangco/CS143/blob/master/HW3/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30/src/demo/fabric/Employee.java, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-utilities-1.4-en/connector-j-fabric-example.html.

Comment: no i'm running it from terminal on my macbook air.
hmm intresting it's all my dependency's you can see up here. that was an intressting link but that's a mysql project. i'll try add that class and package and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried to see your dependencies: `gradle app:dependencies`

Comment: "gradle dependencies" i have nothing with mysql in it.
if i add the package and class that you referred to earlier i can't run "gradle bootRun" it get stuck on 80% but if i run "gradle build" and then run the jar file i get no errors.

Comment: well, you may say you don't have the class Employee in your project, the fact remains it is looking for it. I have difficulties believing if you do a full text search in your project on "Employee", I bet you will find a class, or a config, or a String.. something pointing to this Employee thing hibernate is trying to load. That, or a dummy gradle depencies on one of your other projects which contains such class..

Comment: You don't have add any classes to your project. Try to clean your target directory (or do `gradle clean`) you might have something there. Also you can try to search `demo.fabric.Employee` via Finder or other tool. `Spring Boot` does see the `demo.fabric.Employee` class in the classpath.

Comment: There is something really fishy in this. i have removed everything but my tomcatservers from my eclipse workspace and working directory. i searched the folder in finder to find anything named Employee and i finde nothing. i run "gradle clean" and the "gradle bootRun" but still same error.

Comment: so i stand corrected when i run "gradle dependencies" i see nothing that has todo with mysql.
but when i run "gradle dependencyManagement" i finde two dependencies:
org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc 3.8.11.2
mysql:mysql-connector-java 5.1.39
next question is where does this come from? and how do i exclude them?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem has been resolved by removing redundant mysql-connector-java.jar from java classpath (/lib/ext for me).